# Apple iphone causing button to get squished on website

Tags: html, ios, iphone, cakephp

I am having an issue where on my website a button is getting squished but only on an actual iphone, I can not recreate this on any emulator or simulator to debug this.

I am using html and cakephp

Here is a screenshot

[image]

Here is button code

```
<button id="ca_btn">
<img src="<?= CAKEPHP_URL ?>/img/ca_button.jpg" border="0" />
</button>
```

CSS

```
#ca_btn {

        background-color: white;
        border:none;
    }

    #ca_btn:focus{ outline:0;}
```

Comment: Could you provide some code please?

Comment: whats the css for ca_btn?

Comment: the button looks like its a submit input type instead of a button from the screen shot. you could style most of the button(background colour, border) with css instead of using an image for all that. then have a transparent png for the middle of the button with a bit of padding around it

Comment: any reason that this issue only shows up on the iphone? all other phones display it fine

Comment: I have put an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this to take apple's styling off

```
#ca_btn {
    background-color: transparent;
    border:none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be write media query for this. 
Maybe Min-height could work. 
Try these two things.